# Работа с yaml-файлом

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Есть yaml, его примерное содержание:

```
builds:
- name:name1
 tasks:
     -task1
     -task2
- name:name2
  tasks:
     -task3
     -task4
```

На ввод подается name, нужно вывести все task-и, которые находятся в одном словаре с этим name

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку yaml

```
import yaml 

with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)

def get_tasks(name: str) -> list:
    for item in config['builds']:
        if item['name'] == name:
            return item.get('tasks')
        return [] # Если не нашел данного имени в файле

print(get_tasks('test'))
```

Здесь сначала в переменную config я выгружаю данные из yaml файла, они уже в формате словаря.
Функцией get_tasks я достаю из словаря нужный ключ если он есть и его таски. Если ключ не будет найден то вернётся пустой массив.